# pygame Error : Unknown WAVE format & mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode

Tags: python, pygame, codec, yt-dlp

So i was making an Audio Player, it downloads audio using YT-DLP and then plays it using pygame.mixer.

**the main problem**, i am getting is that pygame Won't Run that Audio instead it would Just give Errors for Different Audio Formats like Wav, Ogg, and Mp3.

For Wav Format I get this Error : `pygame.error: Unknown WAVE format`

For MP3 I get this Error : `pygame.error: mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)`

For Ogg I get this Error : `pygame.error: Not an Ogg Vorbis audio stream`

After Wondering with these things For a While, I think there is *Something Wrong* with the **Codecs**.
Attaching images of 2 Audio Files below (One which is playable with pygame, And one which Gives Errors with it)

> [Working Audio File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX8H1.jpg) And
> [Not Working one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGoRb.jpg)

### For Reference

Here is the yt-dlp Code that i used to download the desired Audio File.

```py
from  yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
(option,C1,C2,C3)=[dict(extractaudio=True,outtmpl='src/backend/temp_audio/%(title)s.mp3'),'https://youtu.be','https://youtube.com','https://www.youtube.com',]

def download_song(link):
        try:
            with YoutubeDL(option) as ydl:
                ydl.download([link])
        except:
            print("Error in Downloading : " + link )
            pass
```

> Command to install the prerequisite : `python -m pip install yt-dlp`

Also for a quick Review, here is the link to the [test Audio File](https://send-anywhere.com/web/downloads/UOGWPV39) i wanted to play .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem Solved

After Asking Tons of people on Discord Servers of [Pygame](https://discord.gg/EaWkr5TVQy) and [yt-dlp](https://discord.gg/FumpHSsjep).

### what i found?

- pygame won't be able to play an Audio file with that Specs.
- we can use yt-dlp with ffmpeg to modify the Audio for making it compatible with pygame.

#### So How can we install ffmpeg :

1. Download ffmpeg : (https://github.com/yt-dlp/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip)
2. Extract the files and find ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe inside the bin folder.
3. Copy those two files to the same folder as your Script.

## Now

After installing ffmpeg, now we need to have some changes in our yt-dlp's code in order to make it run with ffmpeg. Below is the New Code :

```py
from  yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

option={'final_ext': 'mp3',
 'format': 'bestaudio/best',
 'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                     'nopostoverwrites': False,
                     'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                     'preferredquality': '5'}],
 'outtmpl': 'src/backend/temp_audio/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
 'ffmpeg_location': 'YOUR-LOCATION/ffmpeg.exe'}

def download_song(link):
        try:
            with YoutubeDL(option) as ydl:
                ydl.download([link])
        except:
            print(Exception)
            pass
```

Now your Audio Files would Work Perfectly With pygame!

Comment: What is the ffmpeg bit changing about the file?